# JavaFX Scenebuilder Buttons aren't being involked correctly

Tags: java, button, javafx, methods, nullpointerexception

JavaFX buttons aren't being passed on from my Scenebuilder program, and it's causing my code to think they're null. To be more exact: "Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Button.setOnAction(javafx.event.EventHandler)" because "this.calculate" is null at main/lab.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:38) ... 21 more"
I don't want to initialize new Buttons, because then they won't be the buttons I need, and won't work. I don't really know what to do, and I've checked my fx:id to make sure it's the correct one (which it is), so I don't know what's wrong here.

I've tried correcting the fx:id, i've tried initializing new buttons, which doesn't work. I don't really know how it's even wrong to be honest, though it might be an issue in the initialize() method in general that i'm unaware of. Anyways, Here's my controller class that has the code I'm talking about:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button calculate;

    @FXML
    private Button clear;

    @FXML
    private Button exit;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField centimeters;

    @FXML
    private TextField inches;

    @FXML
    private TextField meters;

    @FXML
    private TextField yards;
    
    @FXML
    public  void initialize() {

        calculate.setOnAction(event-> {
            convert();
        });
        clear.setOnAction(e-> {
            centimeters.setText("");
            meters.setText("");
            yards.setText("");
            inches.setText("");
        });
        exit.setOnAction(e->{
            System.exit(0);
        });
    }
  
    public void alignmentFixer() {
        exit.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        clear.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        calculate.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    }
    @FXML
    public void convert() {
        if(!centimeters.getText().isEmpty() && meters.getText().isEmpty() &&
                yards.getText().isEmpty() && inches.getText().isEmpty()) {
            cmConvert(centimeters, inches, meters, yards);
        }
        else if(centimeters.getText().isEmpty() && meters.getText().isEmpty() &&
                yards.getText().isEmpty() && !inches.getText().isEmpty()) {
            inConvert(inches, centimeters,  meters, yards);
        }
        else if(centimeters.getText().isEmpty() && !meters.getText().isEmpty() &&
                yards.getText().isEmpty() && inches.getText().isEmpty()) {
            mConvert(meters, centimeters, inches, yards);
            }
            else if(centimeters.getText().isEmpty() && meters.getText().isEmpty() &&
                    !yards.getText().isEmpty() && inches.getText().isEmpty()) {
                yConvert(yards, centimeters, meters, inches);
                }
    }

    
    public static void cmConvert(TextField centimeters, TextField inches, TextField meters, TextField yards) {
        String centimetersText = centimeters.getText();
        double cm = Double.parseDouble(centimetersText);
        
        // Call the conversion methods and update the GUI with the converted values
        inches.setText(String.valueOf(cmConvertIn(cm)));
        meters.setText(String.valueOf(cmToMeters(cm)));
        yards.setText(String.valueOf(cmToYards(cm)));
    }

    public static void inConvert(TextField inches, TextField centimeters, TextField meters, TextField yards) {
        String inchesText = inches.getText();
        double in = Double.parseDouble(inchesText);
        
        // Call the conversion methods and update the GUI with the converted values
        centimeters.setText(String.valueOf(incToCm(in)));
        meters.setText(String.valueOf(incToMeters(in)));
        yards.setText(String.valueOf(incToYards(in)));
    }
    
    public static void mConvert(TextField meters, TextField centimeters, TextField inches, TextField yards) {
        String metersText = meters.getText();
        double meter = Double.parseDouble(metersText);
        
        // Call the conversion methods and update the GUI with the converted values
        centimeters.setText(String.valueOf(mToCm(meter)));
        inches.setText(String.valueOf(mToInc(meter)));
        yards.setText(String.valueOf(mToYards(meter)));
    }
    
    public static void yConvert(TextField yards, TextField centimeters, TextField inches, TextField meters) {
        String yardsText = yards.getText();
        double yard = Double.parseDouble(yardsText);
        
        // Call the conversion methods and update the GUI with the converted values
        centimeters.setText(String.valueOf(yardsToCm(yard)));
        inches.setText(String.valueOf(yardsToInc(yard)));
        meters.setText(String.valueOf(yardsToMeters(yard)));
    }
    
    public static double cmConvertIn(double cm) {
        return cm / 2.54;
    }

    public static double cmToMeters(double cm) {
        return cm / 100.0;
    }

    public static double cmToYards(double cm) {
        return cm / 91.44;
    }
    public static double incToCm(double in) {
        return in * 2.54;
    }

    public static double incToMeters(double in) {
        return in * 0.0254;
    }

    public static double incToYards(double in) {
        return in / 36.0;
    }
    
    public static double mToCm(double meter) {
        return meter * 100.0;
    }

    public static double mToInc(double meter) {
        return meter * 39.3701;
    }

    public static double mToYards(double meter) {
        return meter * 1.09361;
    }

    public static double yardsToCm(double yard) {
        return yard * 91.44;
    }

    public static double yardsToInc(double yard) {
        return yard * 36.0;
    }

    public static double yardsToMeters(double yard) {
        return yard * 0.9144;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide the (complete) FXML.  Provide the full source code (including package and import statements).  Provide the code that loads the FXML.  Provide the directory layout.  Probably you are importing an awt button rather than a JavaFX button somewhere (e.g. in the controller or the FXML), or maybe you write `new Controller` somewhere, but that is a just a guess given everything missing from the question.  Provide the full stack trace as text formatted as code.

Comment: Controllers don't need (probably shouldn't have) public methods.

Comment: Why the heck are so many methods static? Maybe you want to create a ConversionHelper class?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I believe your error code is here:

```
@FXML
public void convert() {
```

If you set action from button on scenebuilder, you dont need set action from button in initialize, in this case you don't set. Or only set idbutton, don't set action in scenebuilder, and set action without "@FXML" and "public" like a method. I believe if you do this, it's work.

Check if the library from event is not from awt.event to. Check your methods static, is it really necessary so many like this?
I advise make a method with your config button and call in the initialize;